# Impossible Excel-VBA Email Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, email, if-statement

If someone could help me from going insane, my mother would appreciate it.

I have a long list of email addresses (many repeats) with associated Audit Locations.  Basically I need to create **one** email for each email address and populate said email body with a list of all the associated Audit Locations.

e.g.

```
Column One (Email Address)  |  Column 2 (Audit Location)
Yoda1@lightside.org   |  Coruscant
Yoda1@lightside.org   |  Death Star
Yoda1@lightside.org   |  Tatooine
Vader@Darkside.org    |  Death Star
Vader@Darkside.org    |  Coruscant
Jarjar@terrible.org   |  Yavin
```

So far I have created a CommandButton Controlled vba that takes Column One and makes it unique in a new worksheet.

Then I have another sub that creates an email for each unique email address. But I am stuck on the "If...Then" statement.  Essentially, I want to add the information in Column 2 (Audit Location) if the Recipient of the email is the email address in Column One and then continue to append to the email body until the email address no longer equals the recipient email address.  Any guidance would be huge.

```
   Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Call MakeUnique
Call EmailOut
End Sub
Sub MakeUnique()
Dim vaData As Variant
    Dim colUnique As Collection
    Dim aOutput() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    'Put the data in an array
    vaData = Sheet1.Range("A:A").Value

    'Create a new collection
    Set colUnique = New Collection

    'Loop through the data
    For i = LBound(vaData, 1) To UBound(vaData, 1)
        'Collections can't have duplicate keys, so try to
        'add each item to the collection ignoring errors.
        'Only unique items will be added
        On Error Resume Next
            colUnique.Add vaData(i, 1), CStr(vaData(i, 1))
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i

    'size an array to write out to the sheet
    ReDim aOutput(1 To colUnique.Count, 1 To 1)

    'Loop through the collection and fill the output array
    For i = 1 To colUnique.Count
        aOutput(i, 1) = colUnique.Item(i)
    Next i

    'Write the unique values to column B
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Unique"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aOutput, 1), UBound(aOutput, 2)).Value = aOutput

End Sub

Sub EmailOut()
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    On Error Resume Next


    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Unique").Columns("a").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    recip = cell.Value

    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)

        For Each org In Columns("b").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
         If org.Value Like recip Then
      xMailBody = "Body content" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 1" & " " & cell.Offset(0, 3).Value & vbNewLine & _
              [B5] & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2"

             End If
             Next org

On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = recip
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & " " & cell.Offset(0, 3).Value & " " & "Remittance Advice"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a one time thing or something you will need to do multiple times?

Comment: Something I would need to do multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example I quickly wrote the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SendEmails()

 Dim dictEmailData As Object
 Dim CurrentWorkBook As Workbook
 Dim WrkSht As Worksheet
 Dim rngToLookUp As Range
 Dim lngLastRow As Long, i As Long
 Dim arryEmailData As Variant
 Dim objOutlookApp As Object, objOutlookEmail As Object
 Dim varKey As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set CurrentWorkBook = Workbooks("SomeWBName")
    Set WrkSht = CurrentWorkBook.Worksheets("SomeWSName")
    lngLastRow = WrkSht.Cells(WrkSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row   'Find last row with data
    Set rngToLookUp = WrkSht.Range("A2:B" & lngLastRow)              'set range for last row of data

    arryEmailData = rngToLookUp.Value2    'Get the email data from the sheet into an array

        Set dictEmailData = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")      'set the dicitonary object

            On Error GoTo CleanFail
            For i = LBound(arryEmailData, 1) To UBound(arryEmailData, 1)

                varKey = UCase(Trim(arryEmailData(i, 1)))

                    If Not dictEmailData.Exists(varKey) Then
                        dictEmailData(varKey) = vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Trim(arryEmailData(i, 2))

                    Else
                        dictEmailData(varKey) = dictEmailData(varKey) & vbNewLine & Trim(arryEmailData(i, 2))

                    End If

                varKey = Empty

            Next i

            'for each unique key in the dicitonary
            'get the corresponding item
            'created in the loop above
            Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'set the outlook object
            Dim Msg As String, MailBody As String

            For Each varKey In dictEmailData.Keys
                Msg = dictEmailData.Item(varKey)
                Set objOutlookEmail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

                    MailBody = "Dear Colleague," & Msg
                    With objOutlookEmail
                        .To = varKey
                        .Subject = "Remittance Advice"
                        .Body = MailBody
                        .Send
                    End With
                Set objOutlookEmail = Nothing
                Msg = Empty: MailBody = Empty
            Next

    MsgBox "All Emails have been sent", vbInformation

CleanExit:
    Set objOutlookApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    Resume CleanExit

End Sub
```

Add the first occurrence of a `varKey` = email address to the dictionary `dictEmailData` along with its corresponding `item` `dictEmailData(varKey)` = Email body. On the next occurrence of the email address, append to the Email body. Once the dictionary is built, loop through it and send the emails

Printing to the immediate window yields:

[image]

Comment: rickmanalexander:  it works flawlessly!!!! You are a saint.  Thank you so much. Question: how would you rate the difficulty of this?  I am in sales but kinda like programing and want to get my chops up so I would be nice to know how hard your solution is as a benchmark

Comment: @EvanSkywalker You are most welcome! Also, if you could do me a favor and mark my answer as the answer, that way this post can be closed, I would really appreciate it.

As for difficulty rating, I would say It depends on what you would rate your current ability at. If you think of yourself as a beginner, then this is solid 10, lol. If you are intermediate, then I would say a 6.5 ish, and advanced I would say like a 1. In each case I am considering 0 to be the most trivial and 10 to be the most difficult.

Comment: marked!  Your rating makes sense to me.  I'm definitely a beginner and understand about 50% of what you coded.  I guess i want to set my goal to be an intermediate...advance scares me and probably makes sense to pay someone so i don't blow up my computer.